# Editing php so I can insert HTML?

Tags: php

I have some php where i would like to insert html where it says //do stuff.

```
<?php $cat = 8; //8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)){
        //do stuff
    }
?>
```

I would ideally like it be something like. But not sure where to close and reopen the php tags.

```
<?php $cat = 8; //8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)){
        <div id="testing">Im some test content here</div>
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to close and open the php tags, you can use `echo` instead. Just make sure to escape the quotes with a `\`

```
<?php
    $cat = 8;
    if (in_category($cat)){
        echo "<div id=\"testing\">Im some test content here</div>";
    }
?>
```

Otherwise, you could close/reopen the php tags like so:

```
<?php
    // php
?>

<!-- HTML -->

<?php
    // more php
?>
```

The benefit of echoing, however is you can easily slip in some php variable's value.

```
<?php
    $name = "John";
    echo "<b>$name</b>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is using the php `echo` function. More on the [echo](https://www.php.net/echo) function here.

```
<?php $cat = 8; // 8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)) {
      echo "<div id='testing'>I am some test content.</div>"
    } // if
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $cat = 8;
  if (in_category($cat)) {
?>
<div id="testing">Im some test content here</div>
<?php } ?>
```

`div#testing` will be printed if the `in_category($cat)` return `TRUE`.

Comment: it's best not to assume short php tags (`<?` vs `<?php` ) as short tags are not always available.

Comment: yeah, you are right. maybe we have the different `php.ini` setting. let me edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine your document is by default HTML the  begin and end PHP blocks. So you can split your block into two blocks of php as follows, and it will still keep it's program login

```
<?php 
    $cat = 8; //8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)){
       ?>
           <div id="testing">Im some test content here</div>
       <?php    
    }
?>
```

It's just stylistically kind of awkward, but that's the way PHP goes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two different ways.

1)

```
<?php
    $cat = 8; //8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)){
?>
    <p>some html here</p>
<?php } ?>
```

2)

```
<?php
    $cat = 8; //8 is changed to be the category you need
    if (in_category($cat)){
        echo "<p>some html here</p>";
    }
?>
```